# Returning data from multiple Mongoose models

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Hey guys so I am trying to find the best way to go about using mongoose with node and express. Once a user is logged in, I want to grab all data for the user that is spread across multiple collections/mongoose models. Here is an example I started where I get all classes for a specific user:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    email: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
    school: String,
    teacher: Boolean,
    admin: Boolean,
    moderator: Boolean,
    birthday: Date
});

userSchema.getClasses = function (userId) {
    User.find({_id: userId}, function (err, user) {
        Groups.find({
            _id: { $in: [user.groups]},
            type: "class"
        }, function(err, data){
            console.log(data);
            return(data);
        });
    });
}

var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

Basically I have an a key in my users table called 'group' which is an array of keys that pertain to specific documents in my groups table. I want to return all groups with the type 'class'.

My other concern with this whole process is the fact that I want to grab different data using different functions which will probably give me async problems. Here is my route so you can see what I am trying to achieve. I added assignments as an example.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    //user not logged in
    if(!req.session.user){
        res.redirect('/login');
    }else{
        //get groups
        var classes = User.getClasses(req.session.user._id);
        //get assignments
        var assignments = ExampleModel.getAssignments(req.session.user._id);
        console.log(req.session.user.firstName);
        res.render('home/index.jade', {classes: classes, assignments: assignments});
    }
});
```

Comment: you are missing the `groups` field in the `userSchema`, and if you have 2 different unrelated issues, post 2 different questions.

Comment: In addition you use var classes = User.getClasses(req.session.user._id); as a synchron call, but its async due to the find

Comment: Groups in included but I did not include it because it was not relevant to my question. @Dafuck - my question states that I am trying to achieve the following without using nested calls. I know that the example will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, I'd keep my models separate from each other and only define functions pertaining to those models within that file. I'd also make the functions return their response via a callback. If not, the functions that follow will probably execute before the DB query has finished. In your code example, res.render could (and probably will) execute before classes and assignments are populated.

Change the User model (in ./models/user.js) to something like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    other fields here...
});

var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

and then, for each function define it as follows:

```
module.exports.getUserByEmail = function(email, callback){
    User.findOne({email: email }, callback);
}
```

That's just an example but you will probably use something similar to get the user during a login function.

Then in the routes file you'd import the User model (and other models you need to use, e.g. Groups) as follows at the top of the file (./routes/users.js):

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var User = require('../models/user');
var Group = require('../models/group');
```

(Assuming you've got routes in a routes folder and models in a models folder.)

Then, during your route you can fetch the data you want as follows:

```
router.get('/', function(req,res) {
    var email = req.user.email; // If you store it there.
    User.getUserByEmail(email, function(err, user) {
        if (err) throw err;
        // Check for an error
        // Now do something with the user object.
        console.log(user._id);
        Group.getUserGroups(user._id, function(err,groups) {
            if (err) throw err;
            // now you have some groups
            res.render('views/file.jade',{ /* vars */ });
        });
    });
});
```

OK, so that's fairly rough. But that's how you do it without Promises. The key is to make sure you don't execute the next function before the previous one has executed and to keep your models separate so your code is more manageable.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: That makes sense. Do you know of a way to grab the data without nesting every Model call within the other? If I grab data from say 5 different models, I am going to have some crazy nesting lol.

Comment: Welcome to what is known as "Callback Hell". It isn't uncommon to nest many functions and get Christmas Tree style code. There are various Promise libraries (Bluebird is one example off the top of my head) that help you refactor this kind of code but that's a different question.